# How do I get an Epson perfection V200 photo scanner working?

Tags: scanner, epson

I'm new to Ubuntu.  I installed 12.04 64bit, PC is working great, but I can't get my scanner to work.

I tried to 'just scan' with simple-scan, but I got the following error

`"error: no scanner detected, please check your scanner is connected an powered on"`
But the Scanner is powere on.

I use an Epson perfection V200 photo scanner via USB.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? How did you try to install them? Any error messages?

Comment: I git my printer to work, took a few printer reboots, until the name came up.

Comment: scanner still doesn't work. it's a Epson perfection V200 photo, connected via usb. I tried to 'just scan' with simple-scan, error: no scanner detected, please check your scanner is connected an powered on, and it is

Comment: This site works better when there's one post per issue, can you ask a separate question about your printer if it's still an issue?

Answer (score 3):

I found this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7539612) where others had trouble installing that scanner.
It looks like you need to download the drivers off the [manufacturers webpage](http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/scan/DL2.do), this [FAQ](http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/faq/id000651.php) may be helpful in explaining what packages you need, it looks to me like you will need these three packages:

- Data Package under "deb package"

  ```
  iscan-data_1.13.0-1_all.deb
  ```
- Core Packages under "deb 64bit package [libltdl7] (for Ubuntu 8.10 or later)"

  ```
  iscan_2.28.1-3.ltdl7_amd64.deb
  iscan-plugin-gt-f670_2.1.2-1_amd64.deb
  ```

Once you have them downloaded, you should just be able to double click on them and Ubuntu Software Center will open and ask you if you want to install them.

I hope this helps.